# Create nested list from Multidimensional Array with sveral keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i need create list from this array

```
 [records] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 665
                [productGroupID] => 665
                [name] => AUDIO/VIDEO VALDKOND
                [showInWebshop] => 1
                [positionNo] => 619
                [added] => 1362673935
                [lastModified] => 1364198793
                [subGroups] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 557
                                [productGroupID] => 557
                                [name] => VIDEO
                                [showInWebshop] => 1
                                [positionNo] => 1229
                                [added] => 1361340146
                                [lastModified] => 1362131355
                                [subGroups] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 565
                                                [productGroupID] => 565
                                                [name] => TELERID
                                                [showInWebshop] => 1
                                                [positionNo] => 642
                                                [added] => 1361340916
                                                [lastModified] => 1397208602
                                                [subGroups] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 269
                                                                [productGroupID] => 269
                                                                [name] => Teler kuni 15"
                                                                [showInWebshop] => 1
                                                                [positionNo] => 1454
                                                                [added] => 1361281340
                                                                [lastModified] => 1363594045
                                                                [subGroups] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [1] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 500
                                                                [productGroupID] => 500
                                                                [name] => Teler 19-29"
                                                                [showInWebshop] => 1
                                                                [positionNo] => 1459
                                                                [added] => 1361284369
                                                                [lastModified] => 1379684581
                                                                [subGroups] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [2] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 509
                                                                [productGroupID] => 509
                                                                [name] => Teler 32"
                                                                [showInWebshop] => 1
                                                                [positionNo] => 1460
                                                                [added] => 1361284370
                                                                [lastModified] => 1363594480
                                                                [subGroups] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )



                                                    )

                                            )
```

how can i remove all values beside productGroupID and name?

what i made sofar

```
function list($element){
    foreach($element as $value){
        if(!is_array($value)){
            echo "<li>";
            echo $value;
        }else{
            echo "<ul>";
            r($value);
            echo "</li>";
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
}

echo "<ul>";
echo list($output['records']).";
echo "</ul>";
```

this prints all values. i cant figure out, how print only 2 needed values of each sub-array

Comment: Do you want to keep your subgroups as sublist of main list, or you just want to print one level list which contains all _productGroupIds_ and _names_? One important thing, I think you should change name of your function, because [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) is language construct.

Comment: marian0  i want keep all subroups exactly as in array-s 

 I know about list(), just changed function name because it was just l before posting :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over arrays of arrays. Then all what you have to do is printing informations which you need and check if there is not empty subarray. If it is, call recursively again listing function. Below is a working code example. You still pass `$output['records']` to this function as argument.

```
function list_elements($elements) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo $element['productGroupID'] . ':' . $element['name'];
        if (!empty($element['subGroups'])) {
            list_elements($element['subGroups']);
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```